# Testing out GNU screen hardstatus changes in .screenrc

Tags: gnu-screen

Does anyone have recommendations for testing out changes to my hardstatus in .screenrc? Closing and re-opening screen seems inefficient. Perhaps there's a way to reload .screenrc from screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bah, answering my own question for reference to others:

```
screen -X hardstatus string 'test'
```

Documentation [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Invoking-Screen.html#Invoking-Screen).

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `colon` command (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>:</kbd>) and just enter your hardstatus command there.

Answer (score 3):

:source ~/.screenrc

Works just like source for shell startup scripts.